# SQL - How do you select the first row (or any unique row) of multiple rows with the same ID?

Tags: sql, ms-access, greatest-n-per-group

Let's say I have a query result that looks as follows:

```
ID    NAME    Phone
----  ----    -----
1     Bob     111-111-1111
1     Bob     222-222-2222
1     Bob     333-333-3333
2     Stan    555-555-5555
3     Mike    888-888-8888
3     Mike    777-777-7777
```

I want to return just a single row instance of each ID value.  It doesn't matter to me which one of the multiple rows I get - the first in the set is ok.

So a possible result would be:

```
ID    NAME    Phone
----  ----    -----
1     Bob     111-111-1111
2     Stan    555-555-5555
3     Mike    888-888-8888
```

Comment: @Tom - right now Access 2010 (yes I'm embarrassed to admit it) but really my question is meant to be as general as possible.

Comment: Heh... no reason to be embarrassed. Sometimes Access is the right tool for the job. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For SQL Server **[edit] and MS Access**, you can do

```
SELECT [ID], [Name], MIN(Phone) as PhoneNumber
FROM PhoneNumbers
GROUP BY [ID], [Name]
```

This will return

```
ID    NAME    Phone
----  ----    -----
1     Bob     111-111-1111
2     Stan    555-555-5555
3     Mike    777-777-7777
```

You might want to add some sort of unique key to the table, just a thought.

Comment: Thanks.  This isn't a table but rather a result from a previous query.  I am going to quickly try this out...

Comment: Alternatives to Min() are Max(), First() and Last(). The latter two will return different data based on the sort order.

Comment: How can you accomplish this with many columns though that would need to be aggregated with a MIN() statement? I may end up just writing it all out.

Answer (score 1):

We can probably also help you in a direction, if you provide us with the T-SQL statement that gave you the first results you got, with some information how that can be re-written to get the results you wanted.

Comment: I guess I was thinking it shouldn't matter since I could arrive at this result set in multiple different ways.  I really only need to solve from this point forward.